# Event re-sizing does not work when dragging from start date

Tags: fullcalendar

I've tried this from the demos and my own code using both the 1.64 and 2.0 beta versions, but I can still only re-size by dragging from the end date. The docs seem to indicate this is supported and describe the eventStartEditable flag, but this seems to have no effect. Is there something I'm missing with this?

Comment: You'll be more likely to get help if you post a code sample with your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think fullcalendar has this ability. It says that the start time is editable through dragging, not resizing. http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/eventStartEditable/

From the fullcalendar docs:

> "Allow events' start times to be editable through dragging."